# Stop pinned tabs changing in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, google-chrome-extensions

Can I prevent my pinned tabs in Chrome from changing domain? Here's what keeps happening:

- I pin Gmail
- I inadvertently go to that tab (I have a lot of tabs open, so visually there's no difference) and open [another url](http://poniesandunicorns.com/)
- I close Chrome, and next time I open it, it has the other url in the pinned tab

What I would like is for Chrome to throw up a dialog, or simply just prevent me from changing the domain of a tab once I've pinned it. Is this possible?

Comment: I also have a similar issue. I haven't been able to find any suitable solution.

Comment: Pinned tabs are not designed to be stuck on one URL. This is a user error, and the browser shouldn't stop you from going to another URL in that tab. It's not a browser issue at all, and they shouldn't have to fix it.

Comment: @Randolph I'm not implying this is a browser error, but still what I want is an extension to help me avoid making user errors!

Comment: I have the opposite problem in Mozilla Firefox! I can't change the URL without unpinning the (new) URL, but if I wouldn't have too many tabs I wouldn't have pinned the tab (in which I want to do some real work) in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe there is an extension that will keep your tab from changing the URL, pinned or otherwise.

Comment: I have the opposite problem in Firefox, as it acts as OP wants it to.

Answer (score 2):

I created an extension that tries to keep the tab on the same page. When you click on any link it will open that link in a new tab rather than replacing the current tab. If you type a different URL in the location bar, it won't open a new tab. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to prevent that through the Chrome extension APIs.

https://github.com/pmcelhaney/static-pinned-tab-chrome-extension